# Server and client on two different networks with python?

Tags: python, network-programming

I have these two python scripts.

The server :

```
#!/bin/env python

#--*-- coding:UTF-8 --*--

import socket
connexion = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = input("Ip : ")
port = int(input("Port : "))
connexion.connect((host, port))
print("The connection with {} is done.".format(host, port))
started = True

while started:
    choice = int(input(" [1] Command\n [2] Leave\n > "))
    if choice == 1:
        command = input(" Command : ")
        connexion.send(command.encode())
        retour = connexion.recv(1024).decode('latin1')
        print(retour)

        if choice == 2:
            connexion.send("exit")
            connexion.close()
            break
```

And the client :

```
#!/bin/env python

#--*-- coding:UTF-8 --*--

import socket
import subprocess

connexion = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = ''
port = 631
connexion.bind((host,port))
connexion.listen(5)
connexion_client, infos_connexion = connexion.accept()
started = True

while started:
    rcv_cmd = connexion_client.recv(1024)
    rcv_cmd = rcv_cmd.decode()
    if rcv_cmd != "exit":
        cmd = subprocess.Popen(rcv_cmd, shell=true, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr =subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE )
        out = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.sdterr.read()
        connexion_client.send(out)
    else:
        started = False
        conexion.close()
        exit
```

These two scripts work perfectly on my local network, but if I want to use it on two different networks, how can I do that? Do you have any link/tips on how to learn how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean across two subnets that you host locally? Or do you mean between two different [public IPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Public_address)?

Comment: I mean two different public IPs :)

Comment: cool! So what you would need to do is called [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve data transfer between those two servers, you will need to [port forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) the computer running the server. To do this, you need to have access to your router's control panel. Then the instructions vary depending on your router, but you need to tell the router to forward the server's local IP and port to the public IP and port.

After that, you should be able to connect to your server from the client using the public IP of the server's router.